# I can't debug my script in vscode (mac) due to python path issues

Tags: pythonpath

Im a totally novice to python and vscode; I wish to start learn the language. However, Im stuck and Im not even started :D

In terminal, within Python3, with `import sys` `print(sys.executable)` I got the path I needed to copy-paste in vscode's settings (i.e., simple additional line to the JSON file with python.pythonpath).

---

(1) However, when Im running a simple print script the terminal in vscode says "The default interactive shell is now zsh.To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit..." and asks for password. When I insert the password, I get a lengthy connection error:

```
hsh: Credentials could not be verified, username or password is invalid.  Credentials could not be verified, username or password is invalid.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 51, in main
    launcher.connect(host, port)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/launcher/__init__.py", line 34, in connect
    sock.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 51, in main
    launcher.connect(host, port)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/launcher/__init__.py", line 34, in connect
    sock.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 51, in main
    launcher.connect(host, port)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/launcher/__init__.py", line 34, in connect
    sock.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
```

### my name is annonymized with xxx :)

(2) when I try to debug I get the following error: "The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid. Source: Python (extensions)

This is how the json file looks like:

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
}
```

Any idea how I can overcome this first big hurdle?

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your posting to make it readable. The "Code Sample" button in the editor may be helpfull for than.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project folder in a path that has a space " " in it?  I had this same message when the venv I was using was under a path that had a space in it. When I moved the venv to a folder without the space it started working again.  It doesn't look like it based on your description, but it was the error I had.

This is what my .launch file looks like when I got it working. The file you have looks so much different I figured it might have something to do with that as well?

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "classify_x",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "classify_x.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["orig.csv","output.csv"],
        },    
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```